# The property X is of type 'Geometry' which is not supported by the current database provider

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, postgis

I was provided with a `PostgreSQL` database and currently trying to bind `EF Core` to it. As the DB already exists I tried to scaffold a context, and I succeeded with warnings similar to:

> Could not find type mapping for column 'x.Polygons.Shape' with data type 'x.geometry'. Skipping column.

I skipped all such columns at scaffolding time and tried restoring them manually:

```
public sealed class Polygon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateOnly CreationDate { get; set; }
    public DateOnly ModificationDate { get; set; }
    public DateOnly SurveyDate { get; set; }
    public Geometry Shape { get; set; } //This (and similar) column was added manually
}
```

After that I extracted and patched the scaffolded entity configuration to a separate class like this:

```
public sealed class PolygonConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Polygon>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Polygon> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Polygons", Constants.DatabaseScheme);
        builder.HasIndex(e => e.Id, "idx_Polygons_ID");
        builder.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        builder.Property(x => x.Shape).HasColumnType("geometry"); //This one was added manually as well
    }
}
```

Referenced all required libraries and registered my context:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IMyContext, MyContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(Constants.ConnectionString)));
```

But it does not work. I tried to query entities with `Geometry` type. I also tried to create the initial EF migration (to recreate the DB) but ended up with absolutely the same error:

> The property 'Polygon.Shape' is of type 'Geometry' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

P.S. I have already checked some guides [here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/) and [here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nts.html) - they didn't help as I have met all the prerequisites

Comment: You are missing UseNetTopologySuite

Comment: @ErikEJ, thank you very much, my eyes were really blurry. Please post it as answer so I could resolve it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just missing:

```
UseNetTopologySuite
```

EF Core supports mapping to spatial data types using the NetTopologySuite [spatial library](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/ef/core/modeling/spatial).

| EF Core Provider | Spatial NuGet Package |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer | Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite |
| Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite | Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.NetTopologySuite |
| Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory | NetTopologySuite |
| Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL | [Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.NetTopologySuite) |
| Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql | Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.NetTopologySuite |
| Devart.Data.MySql.EFCore | Devart.Data.MySql.EFCore.NetTopologySuite |
| Devart.Data.PostgreSql.EFCore | [Devart.Data.PostgreSql.EFCore.NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.PostgreSql.EFCore.NetTopologySuite) |
| Devart.Data.SQLite.EFCore | Devart.Data.SQLite.EFCore.NetTopologySuite |
| Teradata.EntityFrameworkCore | Teradata.EntityFrameworkCore.NetTopologySuite |

Comment: where should I put it?

Comment: @user230910https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/ef/core/modeling/spatial